# ARKit reference image loaded at different size than in Assets

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am running the sample project for ARKit and I am trying to add my own image. There is a weird behaviour as the image is loaded at a different size than set in the asset inspector:

[image]

[image]

As can be seen, the image is (almost) an A5 size (14.8 x 19.7 cm), but it is loaded by ARKit at 14.8 x 11.1 cm. The metadata of the picture also has a height greater than the width: `3024 x 4032`. The image is a `jpg`.

To be noted, there are no changes made in the code from the sample project from Apple which I am currently running.

Another note, the app detects the image successfully, but the detected area on the piece of paper is clipped to the dimensions printed in console.

A third note: I observed that the 11.1 cm dimension would be obtained if the image would be rotated 90 degrees (i.e. consider the height to be 14.8 cm, then the width would be 11.1 cm). This looks weird enough as nothing points to anything like that. I also double checked my image, but there seems nothing wrong with it.

The question is: is there anything I am missing or things I have to consider/do with my sample image? Is this a known issue or is there any workaround to make ARKit load my image with the expected dimensions?

**Update**

The source of the Apple's sample project: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/detecting_images_in_an_ar_experience

An extra side note: I only experienced this issue with a single image file. It was an image taken by an iPhone and converted from `HEIC` to `jpg` using an online converter (which I cannot find anymore). Anyway, the image file did not seem to have any anomalies.

Comment: As there are several  sample projects for `ARKit` could you please update your question with the title and link of the sample project (for context).